# Notational Doubt Jech set theory

Tags: set-theory

In Jech's Introduction to Set Theory he writes

If there is a set $A$ such that for all $x$, $P(x)$ implies $x \in A$. then $ \{ x \in A  |  P(x) \} $ exists and  moreover does not depend on $A$. What is the meaning of this statement. specifically the does not depend on $A$ part.

Acc. to me such a case could  happen if $A$ is not the parameter in the statement but from what I understand $x$ is not the parameter here because the statement says for all $x$.

I am confused can somebody clear this up

Comment: In this context, $\{x\in A|P(x)\}$ is the set of all $x$ such that $P(x)$. If $B$ is any other set such that $P(x)\Rightarrow x\in B$, then $\{x\in A:P(x)\}=\{x\in B:P(x)\}$.

Comment: but why does this not depend on $A$

Comment: It only depends on the *existence* of some such $A$, not on the specific $A$.

Comment: Because as Maneli Mezbarba said, this works for any set $B$ with the required property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, $\{x\in A|P(x)\}$ is the set of all $x$ such that $P(x)$, that we may write as $\{x|P(x)\}$.

Indeed, one clearly has $\{x\in A|P(x)\}\subset \{x|P(X)\}$. On the other hand, if $P(x)$ holds, then your hypothesis implies that $x\in A$, hence $x\in A$ and $P(x)$, proving the reverse inclusion.

For instance, take $P(x)$ as "$x\subset y$", for a fixed set $y$. Then the axiom of power set says that there exists a set $A$ such that $x\subset y\Rightarrow x\in A$, and one defines $\wp(y)=\{x\in A:x\subset y\}$. However, any other set $B$ such that $x\subset y\Rightarrow x\in B$ yields $\wp(y)=\{x\in B:x\subset y\}$.

The requirement of a set $A$ such that $P(x)\Rightarrow x\in A$ is here to avoid "Russell's paradox" situations.

Comment: what I have understood from the example and please correct me if i am wrong is that - $A $ and $B$ are merely notation as by the power set axiom there will always be some set to which $x$ will belong whether I write that as $A$ or $B$ doesnt matter.

Comment: in the second paragraph  you have proved is that $ \{x \in A|P(x)\}  = \{x|P(x)\}$ by saying $A = B$ if $ A \subset B$ and  $ B \subset A $

Comment: For your first comment: if I understood what you wrote, then you're right, it doesn't matter if you take $A$ or $B$, as long as they satisfy the condition ``if $P(x)$ then $x$ is a member of it''.

For your second comment: you are right, I used the axiom of extension.